# Gridelments with background image

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-gridelements

I'm using Gridelements on my TYPO3 v8 project. I would like to show a background image for the gridelement frame taken from the related file of this gridelements record. We can see this file under the appearance TAB. I think this is a sys_file_reference.

Can I just use it in frontend to make a background image for this gridelements section?

```
# Two Columns
2 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
2 {
    columns {
        # 101 reflects colPos
        101 < .default
        101 {
            wrap = <div class="span6">|</div>
        }
        102 < .default
        102 {
            wrap = <div class="span6">|</div>
        }
    }
    wrap =<div class="row-container visible-first"> <div class="container-fluid"><div class="content-inner row-fluid">|</div></div></div>
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you render the grid using Fluid or just TypoScript? Can you post your code?

Comment: For the moment i use typoscript, but if i need fluid i will add it, please tell me how i can fix this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be possible to do that with TypoScript, but I'll post here my solution, which is based on Fluid.

The solution is based on the following assumptions:

1) you have already created an extension of your own that acts as "frontend configuration provider"; I'll call it "yourext".
If you need help about this topic, please join the TYPO3 Slack channel (https://typo3.slack.com/) and ask for help.

2) the background image will be stored in the *media* field, that is related to the "files" palette you see in the appearance tab of gridelements

3) EXT:yourext depends on gridelements.

TS Config

```
#Define the element with 2 columns:

tx_gridelements.setup.twocolumnscontainer {
  title = 2 col container
  description = whatever description you want
  iconIdentifier = 
  config{
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 1
    rows {
      1 {
        columns {
            1 {
                name = column 1
                colPos = 100
            }
            2 {
                name = column 2
                colPos = 101
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

TypoScript constants:

```
styles.templates.templateRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/ 
styles.templates.partialRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
styles.templates.layoutRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentElements/
```

TypoScript Template:

```
# the default gridelement object will be a reference to the default fluidtemplate object shipped with TYPO3 8

lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup.cObject =<  lib.contentElement

#define the element with 2 colums as copy of the default object
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup.twocolumnscontainer < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup.twocolumnscontainer {
cObject.templateName = GridElementTwoColumns
cObject.dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
        references.fieldName = media
        as = backgroundimage 
    }

  }
}
```

EXT:yourext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:

```
<?php
 defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();
 //prevent defining global variables 
 call_user_func(function () {
 // only allow 1 image
 $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['gridelements_pi1']['columnsOverrides']['media']['config']['maxitems']=1;
});
```

EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/GridElementTwoColumns.html (use your own html code, here I just use the Bootstrap standard as example)

```
<f:layout name="Default"/>
<f:section name="Main">

<f:if condition="{backgroundimage.0}">
{f:uri.image(image:backgroundimage.0)}
</f:if>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_100-> f:format.raw()}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_101-> f:format.raw()}
    </div>          
</div>
</f:section>
```

I think this should be sufficient.

**Final Note**

Using the media field you will not be able to use the "cropping tool"; to do that you have to store your images in the *image* field of the tt_content database table; this means you'll have to alter the TCA of gridelements to show the "images" tab.

Comment: Thank you Riccardo for this full description really appreciate it, i will try this solution and i'll be back with feedback.

Answer (score -1):

**Flexform:**

```
    <backgroundimage>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>Hitergundbild</label>
                        <config>
                            <type>inline</type>
                            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                            <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                            <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                            <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                            <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                            <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                            <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride type="array">
                                <config>
                                    <appearance>
                                        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                                        <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,png,svg,gif</elementBrowserAllowed>
                                    </appearance>
                                </config>
                            </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                            <foreign_match_fields type="array">
                                <fieldname>image</fieldname>
                            </foreign_match_fields>
                            <appearance type="array">
                                <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                                <headerThumbnail>
                                    <field>uid_local</field>
                                    <height>64</height>
                                    <width>64</width>
                                </headerThumbnail>
                            </appearance>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
</backgroundimage>
```

**HTML Template**

```
style="background-image:url({f:uri.image(src:'{data.flexform_backgroundimage}',treatIdAsReference:'1')})"
```